# Connect e4 RCP and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, rcp

I did hibernate tutorial separately and eclipse rcp tutorial separately
later I tried to include hibernate in build path in rcp application and assumed it would work.
But it does not when I need to use hibernate it errors out

```
      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry
```

when I tried adding org.hibernate dependencies to Manifest.MF it prevents from rcp to instantiate saying

```
      Missing Constraint :Require-Bundle
```

Please not that I did go in configuration and clicked add required plugins but it now asks for Java 1.8 when I am working on 1.7 Can some one give me clear instructions on how to make hibernate work with eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had not added EclipseBuddy in the plugin and main applications Manifest.MF file once I added them isuue was resolved.